# Redirecting console output to a Python string

Tags: python, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I capture the stdout output of a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923079/how-can-i-capture-the-stdout-output-of-a-child-process)

I'm running a `cat`-like program in bash from Python:

```
   import os

   os.system('cat foo.txt')
```

How do I get the output of the shell command back in the Python script, something like:

```
   s = somefunction('cat foo.txt')
```

?

**UPD**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python) is a related thread.

Comment: dupe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923079/subprocess-and-stdout/923108

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

(stdout, stderr) = Popen(["cat","foo.txt"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()
print stdout
```