# Async read console output with python while process is running

Tags: python, process, console

I want to run a long process (calculix simulation) via python.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994902/redirecting-console-output-to-a-python-string) one can read the console string with `communicate()`.

As far as I understand the string is returned after the process is completed? Is there a possibility to get the console output while the process is running?

Comment: Your process `calculix` simulation write data on console while running ?

Comment: yes, sure it writes to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`subprocess.Popen.poll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check process terminates or not.

```
while sub_process.poll() is None:
    output_line = sub_process.stdout.readline()
```

This will give you runtime output.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen([your args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while sp.poll() is None: # sp.poll() returns None while subprocess is running
  output = sp.stdout # here you have acccess to the stdout while the process is running
  # Do stuff with stdout
```

Notice we don't call communicate() on subprocess here.