# Capture standard output for Python child spawned by external package

Tags: python

I would like to capture in a file the standard output by a child Process spawned by an external package.

I can NOT simply redirect sys.stdout to a file, as this does not capture the output of new processes ([How can I capture the stdout output of a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923079/how-can-i-capture-the-stdout-output-of-a-child-process)).

But unfortunately, I also can NOT simply use subprocess or the terminal to capture stdout, since I am not spawning the process -- it is spawned by the code in an external Python package.

Specifically, I am using the API to the package pystan. Some of the functions in this package spawn child MCMC runs that write to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

I only see two ways to do this:

- monkey-patch `pystan` (might take several patches)
- monkey-patch `subprocess` (might get more info than you want)

I would go with the `subprocess` monkey-patch: write your own version of `Popen` (or whatever `pystan` is using, and replace the `subprocess` version with your own.  Your version would track `STDOUT` and save it somewhere you could get at it.

Roughly, something like this:

```
import subprocess
original_Popen = subprocess.Popen

def my_Popen(..., stdout=PIPE, ...):  # or somesuch
    ...

subprocess.Popen = my_Popen

# call pystan here

subprocess.Popen = original_Popen # if needed
```