# How to get the text that is shown in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

My script uses an external module which prints to the console some information when something happens, I need to capture the moment this new information has been printed, so in other words, I need to access the current console text and check if this information has been printed out.

after searching a bit online I found this:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = buffer = StringIO()
# Code
buffer.getvalue()
```

But for some reason this doesn't capture the console outputs of the module I am using, it only captures the `print` statements I use, is there a way for me to get the current console text?

Comment: Accidentally wrote `stderr` instead of `stdout`, edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, apparently, the module I am using is written in C++, and `sys.stdout` is written only for python, meaning that any changes won't affect modules that are compiled outside of python.

So in order to capture the outputs of the C++ module, I came across this code from another answer:

```
capture = py.io.StdCaptureFD()
# ...
out, err = capture.readouterr()
```

which works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor other processes (your external module) output then I would execute this process from monitoring script and then capture its output using *subprocess* module.

See for example this thread: [How can I capture the stdout output of a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923079/how-can-i-capture-the-stdout-output-of-a-child-process)